# Unable to install Actuators to a LABVIEW based Engineering Test System

Tags: software, labview

I need to install an actuators to LABVIEW base test system because the old actuators are defective. We cannot purchase the old actuators because they are obsolete. The old actuators communicated using the COM ports 1 and 8. The COM port are hard coded in the LABVIEW program. The new actuators communicate via a USB interface. But COM ports 1 & 8 not available. The systems states that they are "in use".

The LABVIEW based test systems is running on a Window 7 machine. Is there a way to point the new actuator USB interfaces to COM port 1 and 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might need to do is to remove the "in use" port and then assign the respective COM port. Follow is a suggested set of steps.

- Open command prompt (Start > Run) and type: **cmd**
- At the prompt type: **set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1**
- Followed by C:> devmgmt.msc

  [image: Administrator Window]
  <sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>
- Next in the device manager view > Show hidden files

[image: Device Manager-1]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

- Expand COM by clicking on the "+" and uninstall the COM ports

[image: Device Manager-2]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

- From device manager select the COM port that the device is currently attach  to and right click

[image: COM Port Configuration]

- Select Properties -> Port Setting -> Advance -> Assign the desired  COM port from the drop down

[image: Advance Setting for COM port]
<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

Let me know how it works out for you